# How to create a standalone macro?

Tags: macros

Is it possible to create a stand alone macro that executes clicks at x,y coords with keystrokes on it aswell? Would it be possible thru console (in some language?!), or maybe even a simple batch file? Is there documentation on how to do this? The format is kinda this, but this is through an application and that is not practical for me.

```
LButtonClick 1575,260
Wait 200
LButtonClick 859,621
KeyStrokes "text here" //it should insert and or write this text .
LButtonClick 898,717
LButtonClick 972,600
```

and this would repeat it self but with different coords.

Comment: Did you check google?

Comment: yes, i can't find any standalone guide.

Comment: Please at least tag with relevant programming language etc.

Comment: I don't know what the language i should use tho, i'm guessing java would do it from the answear written by tucuxi.

Comment: is this for a specific platform?

Comment: Not it is not for a specific platform and i dont understand why the downratings but ok. If you do downrate a question at least explain why, since it fullfils all the rules, question, brief code and search done.

Comment: Your question is too generic, that code is not "real code" since it is not really any programming language, and the methods to do what you ask are totally different depending on the OS used, so it is not possible to give an answer.

Comment: I'm guessing the question relates to Windows (?) but it's way too vague as it stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can also use python and use [**pywinauto**](https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/) to automate windows stuff.

Comment: seems like a good way to do it, thanks ;)

Comment: there are more modules in python to do the same stuff..
https://code.google.com/p/swapy/, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopy/

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no stand-alone way to automate UI actions under MS Windows. Not from .bat files certainly, since they are not aware anything UI-related.

You can certainly do this in a variety of languages. For example, Java has had support for generating UI events for a long time - see the [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class.

Comment: the page is not available or does not exist.

Comment: fixed - there was some junk at the end of the URL

Comment: windows API can generate mouse events http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx. I am not sure if it can be called with Rundll or not http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787 but your answer seem wrong, so I will give you a -1.

Comment: @LtWorf - you cannot call [SendInput()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx) via rundll: it should take params like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376957%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - otherwise, rundll will [refuse](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787) to run it.

Comment: Still the "No, there is no stand-alone way to automate UI actions under MS Windows." sounds wrong to me.

Comment: @LtWorf - straw man, I was referring to UI automation with **bat files**. The standard way (TM) of scripting things (specially if UI-related) in Windows is to use VB or C#; .bat files are not used for this. Care to prove me wrong?